# GSON serialize the field only in certain cases

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

Is it possible to serialize a field for certain cases?
I am using a POJO to create a JSON and calling a no-arg constructor and then set up the Object via setter methods. When salary is not set, I get 0 as the default value. Since "employee" is used many times in the same JSON file, I can not use "transient" or "Expose". I suppose writing an ExclusionStrategy would ignore the "employee" and remove it from the whole JSON as well.

```
  {
   "company":{
      "employee":{
         "name":"x",
         "salary":50
      }
   },
   "boss":{
      "employee":{
         "name":"y"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Would using the boxed type (e.g. `Integer`) for 'salary' and using `null` as value be an option? Then Gson would exclude the field (unless `GsonBuilder.serializeNulls()` is used). Otherwise it might be a bit more difficult (but not impossible).

Comment: It worked just fine. Thanks a lot